# Post custom metrics data to New Relic

Tags: java, newrelic

How to post the data to New Relic API using java?

I did not get any proper idea for that. Kindly help me on this with any example or link to check this? how to post metrics data to New Relic API using java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the [newrelic-telemetry-sdk-java](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-telemetry-sdk-java).

Some [examples](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-telemetry-sdk-java/tree/main/telemetry_examples).

Answer (score 0):

See sending custom  [Event API](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/telemetry-data-platform/ingest-apis/introduction-event-api/)  to New Relic

Basically you send regular POST requests with custom NewRelic's metric data

> Data submitted to the Event API uses a compressed JSON format in a simple HTTPS POST request.

Comment: instead of http post, can we do from java using their api?

Comment: @shree this is NewRelic Event API

Comment: Ok. i understood its NewRelic Event API .  i am asking like do we have any jar and using that to connect and post..for example if we use aws s3 ,  com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;  -we can call putObject method putObject(..).....do we have kind of api call in NewRelic?

Comment: Get help from discuss.newrelic.com